# Raspberry pi Jasper speech recognition not working

Tags: python, linux

I follow this tutorial http://jasperproject.github.io/documentation/
I use Debian Jessie so most off them I have to compile.
When I want to run jasper.py I get this error:
Does anyone knows what the problem can be.

> DEBUG:client.diagnose:Checking network connection to server
>   'www.google.com'... DEBUG:client.diagnose:Network connection
>   working DEBUG:**main**:Trying to read config file:
>   '/root/.jasper/profile.yml' DEBUG:client.diagnose:Checking python import 'pocketsphinx'... 
>   DEBUG:client.diagnose:Python package 'pocketsphinx' found:
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pocketsphinx/**init**.py' 
>   WARNING:root:tts_engine not specified in profile, defaulting to
>   espeak-tts' DEBUG:client.diagnose:Checking executable 'aplay'... 
>   DEBUG:client.diagnose:Executable 'aplay' found: '/usr/bin/aplay' 
>   DEBUG:client.diagnose:Checking executable 'espeak'... 
>   DEBUG:client.diagnose:Executable 'espeak' found: '/usr/bin/espeak' 
>   DEBUG:client.vocabcompiler:compiled_revision is
>   'bb74ae36d130ef20de710e3a77b43424b8fa774f' ERROR:root:Error
>   occured! Traceback (most recent call last):   File "jasper.py",
>   line 146, in      app = Jasper()   File "jasper.py",
>   line 109, in **init**
>   stt_passive_engine_class.get_passive_instance(), File
>   "/home/pi/jasper/client/stt.py", line 48, in get_passive_instance
>   return cls.get_instance('keyword', phrases) File
>   "/home/pi/jasper/client/stt.py", line 42, in get_instance
>   instance = cls(**config) File "/home/pi/jasper/client/stt.py",
>   line 126, in **init**     **vocabulary.decoder_kwargs) 
>   TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hmm'

Comment: There is a keyword `hmm` too much. The traceback points to the configuration, can you add all relevant code and the configuration?

Comment: what do you mean with configuration.

Comment: The `profile.yml`. If you have personal information like API keys inside make sure to remove them.

Comment: Klaus, you did not answer anymore Did I post the wrong script or what ?

Answer (score 0):

I paste my stt.py script on pastebin. http://pastebin.com/Cy6ziGPk
Because I could not manage this on this forum.